# How to implement Multi-threading in ewam?

Tags: ewam

I was trying to implement multi-thread functionality in ewam. Can we achieve multi-threading using ewam? how can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a log to documentation on the subject except the manuals the describe how to configure it for wMigrate batches. In general multithreading is dangerous and should only be used for large batch processes that need it.
The best reference material is to study the examples in Wynsure such as `aWFBillingBatchManager`

Comment: Can you suggest what is the purpose of the parameter 'InheritHandle' that is being passed to the method aThread.Create